# Sending image to rom memory stu-540 via webHid api

Tags: rom, wacom, webhid

The goal is to send an image to the rom memory of a Wacom signing device STU-540 using web hid API in the browsers and display it instantly every time I open it again.
The main problem is to find information related.

I have red the documentation of wacom sdk but they don`t give information directly related to web hid api.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/pabloko/Wacom-STU-WebHID